# Cordova plugin ListPicker error on Ripple emulator

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using Cordova within Visual Studio and added the [ListView plugin](https://github.com/roberthovhannisyan/PhoneGap-Plugin-ListPicker). The plugin was added successfully via the config.xml editor screen

When I call `window.plugins.listpicker.showPicker` I can trace all the way to `cordova.exec(_callback, _error_callback, 'ListPicker', 'showPicker', [config])` then Ripple displays the "I Haz Cheeseburger" error on ListPicker.showPicker We seem to be missing some stuff :(

I have verified that the plugin is listed in the plugins folder with other plugins that I am using

Comment: Have you tried to use another emulator like genymotion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Version: You did not do anything wrong, test your app on a actual device or an emulator and it should work fine.

---

Long Version:

> Caution: Ripple doesn’t provide a complete simulation of Cordova APIs or native device capabilities... You can achieve this by testing on actual devices or emulators.

Taken from [here](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ripple-simulator/)
Ripple is just a simulator: It simulates **some** of the capabilities of a real device, not all of them. It seems you can test the  [Cordova core plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/plugins/pluginapis.html) in Ripple, but there is pretty much no support for custom plugins.
I created an empty project Cordova app and just pasted the sample code from the link you provided: In Ripple I get the error you described, while everything works fine, if I run the app on my android device.